# Create DB trigger to Sql DB

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, azure

Im new to DB stuff and I need to create DB trigger to azure SQL DB.

I've create MVC5 project with model first and I have this model which reflect the DB table.

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string EmpAddress { get; set; }
        public string EmpEmail { get; set; }
        public string EmpPhone { get; set; }

    }

    public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
            public DbSet<Employee> EmployeeCollection { get; set; }
        }

}
```

Now I want to create DB trigger for it and I try like following.(I take this example from SO and adjust it...)

```
Create Trigger Dbo.triggerName ON Employee
AFTER INSERT, Update, Delete
AS Begin
  -- Log Deleted Rows and Old Value 
  Insert Into EmployeeCopy(Id ,EmployeeName, EmpAddress,EmpEmail,EmpPhone)
  Select CURRENT_EMPLOYEE, Columns
  From Deleted

  -- Log Inserted Row and New Value 
  Insert Into EmployeeCopy(Id ,EmployeeName, EmpAddress,EmpEmail,EmpPhone)
  Select CURRENT_EMPLOYEE, Columns
  From Inserted
End
```

I want it to create new table which is **EmployeeCopy** and copy all the rows to it.
**so this is my question** (I new to this topic)

```
1. what is the trigger name?
2.Do I write the Insert into right ?
3. Select CURRENT_EMPLOYEE, Columns ..Here Im not sure if this is the right way to write it?
```

Comment: Trigger name can be anything you want to name the trigger as eg. CopyEmployee. Your insert into would look like this - Insert Into EmployeeCopy(Id ,EmployeeName, EmpAddress,EmpEmail,EmpPhone)
  Select Id ,EmployeeName, EmpAddress,EmpEmail,EmpPhon.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert into` statement may be changed (see below) - but you did not specify condition of your select => you will probably insert all rows from your deleted and Inserted tables on each trigger operation.

See more details about insert into, for example, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp).

You should probably write and test your select statement as stand-alone query (just run it from New Query window), When you'll get expected results - put it in the trigger's logic.

Generally, I'll suggest to try each part of your trigger logic as stand-alone statements.

```
Create Trigger dbo.MyTrigger ON Employee
AFTER INSERT, Update, Delete
AS Begin
  -- Log Deleted Rows and Old Value 
  Insert Into EmployeeCopy
   Select (Id ,CURRENT_EMPLOYEE, EmpAddress,EmpEmail,EmpPhone)
   From Deleted
   WHERE Your_conditions_logic_here

  -- Log Inserted Row and New Value 
  Insert Into EmployeeCopy 
   Select  (Id ,CURRENT_EMPLOYEE, EmpAddress,EmpEmail,EmpPhone)
   From Inserted
   WHERE Your_conditions_logic_here
End
```